# Are HTML buttons with no values submitted in a form?

Tags: html

if you have

```
<button class="button yellow" type="submit" 
name="button">Log in</button>
```

and you submit it, what gets posted to the server for the button which has a name but no value attribute?

The reason I ask is that I'm parsing HTML forms, and need to post the named values that send data to the server. I got the others covered, but wasn't sure about button.

Comment: Did you try to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HTML Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-value), a button's value is either determined by its `value` attribute or is an empty string. A button's value is only submitted with the form if the button has a name and is used to initiate form submission. If the button in your example is clicked, the resultant submission will be:

```
"button=" (quotes added)
```

Some browsers (mainly older IE versions) have [incorrect implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes) of this button behaviour that either set the value to the button's contents or submit all button values regardless of initiation source.

Answer (score 1):

`button` does not get posted to `server` when the `form` is posted. Only `input` type's like `text`, `password`, `select` elements etc., which accepts user `inputs` will be posted to the `server`

Answer (score 0):

Button never supplies value to form. It just provides a submit event that tells the browser to submit that form with all the input tags to the action attribute inside your form tag using the method attribute value. Button only provides the event and not the values.

Answer (score 0):

There will be nothing posted to the server for buttons. When you click a button, it invokes the action of `submit`, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out by printing the request.POST in django.
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOOVm.png) shows a "Log in" button with no value but name="button", as asked
The console [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpgOj.png)

```
< QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'9aAx..'], u'sensor': [u'sd1'], u'button':[u'']}>
```

So, in this case, the form is sent as a dictionary and for the buttons the key, value pair is "button" : " ". So, if you try to get value of this button with request.POST.get, you will get NULL.
So, the answer to your question is the form consolidates all the input values, which can be accessed with their 'name' including buttons. If no value is provided, it returns NULL.